# How to find two different matched data for one parent id?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i have to search iron and van. In my search condition iron is in one row and van is in another row. Both are have the same parent id. How did i find the both records in one mysql query.

i'm using this query.

```
SELECT * FROM  `products prod,parents p ` 
WHERE  `p.id` =1 AND prod.name = 'Van' AND prod.name = 'Iron'
```

This is my table

Parent

> ```
>      id    
> ----------
>      1    
>      2
> ```

Child

> ```
>      id   |   name   |   parent   
> ---------------------------------
>      5    |   iron    |     1
>      6    |   van     |     1
>      7    |   jane    |     2
> ```

i want

> ```
> id | name | parent
> ------------------
> 5  | van  | 1
> 6  | iron | 1
> ```

How can i get the output like i mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Use `In and Inner Join`

```
SELECT * FROM  products prod Inner join parents p on p.id=prod.parent 
WHERE  `p.id` =1 AND prod.name In( 'Van' ,'Iron')
```

Comment: How can i use LIKE with this method?

Comment: Like is slower on perfromance so please use IN instead of LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Use OR operator instead of AND

```
SELECT * 
FROM products prod,
     parents p
WHERE p.id=1 AND (prod.name='Van' OR prod.name='Iron')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the query to find out same parent Id should be like this

```
SELECT prod.id,prod.name,p.parent
  FROM  products prod,parents p
WHERE p.id in 
(SELECT  parent FROM parents
    WHERE 2 >=
  (SELECT COUNT(parent) FROM parent WHERE p.id=parent GROUP BY parent)
);
```